# Alguien sabe por que aparece el siguiente error en Unity al momento de exportar a un archivo apk?

Tags: android, unity3d

Error en consola:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
```

He configurado el path del SDK con la ruta donde lo instala el Android Studio

```
introducir el código aquí
```

Y también ya he llenado todos los campos que se requieren en Project Setting Editor.

El Proyecto que intento exportar solamente es una nueva Scene en 3D sin ninguna funcionalidad ya que estaba testando si era algo de código o simplemente no se podía.

Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Javier, dentro de  stderr[ ] no te marca ningún mensaje de error?